# Predicting n'th percentile

Tags: forecasting, prediction, standard-deviation, quantiles

When we use prediction, we can only say levels.

For example:
We have 500 sample data for our walking range. And let's say 90 percentile is 16.0 km and 10th percentile is 0.78 km. Well, can only say that there's a 80% probability that we will walk between 0.78 km - 16 km. Or 90% we will walk less than 26 km and 90% we will walk more than 0.78 km. But is there a way to say 75% we will walk that much instead of giving a range?

Or is percentile the only well-known way to use for such predictions? I know we can use regressions, providing more information but the only information we have is this.

EDIT:
We can only say today we have walked 9km which is 75th percentile. But how can we say that there's a 75% probability to walk 9km tomorrow? Or simply can't we?

EDIT 2:
To be more clear. Is there a way to say: Tomorrow 75% you will walk 8km instead of 75% you will walk less than 8km?

Answer (score 2):

You are essentially looking for a [prediction-interval](/questions/tagged/prediction-interval), specifically for a $[0,0.75]$ interval. Equivalently, you could read up on *quantile forecasts* for a 75% quantile.

There are many ways to calculate such a quantile prediction, including:

- parametric approaches, as in ARIMA: you assume normal noise in the data generating process, predict both the mean and the variance and extract the percentile from the predictive density
- resampling-based approaches, as in most Bayesian treatments: you derive a predictive density and sample from that
- "direct" approaches, where you directly predict your quantile as a point forecast (e.g., [Gneiting, 2011](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2009.12.015))

Whether either one of these is successful will depend on your training data and on the percentiles you are aiming at. Very high (or low) percentiles are typically harder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is, can you say that 75% you will walk 8km tomorrow. Can can we still say that 75% you will walk less than 8km? I mean this is the confusing part here. We can only say this: After walk, you look at the length of walk and you can say that it's #th percentile. But we can say this after job completed.

Comment: Ah. I may have misunderstood. If you want to have a probability of walking *exactly* 75km, then you need a discrete predictive probability distribution (continuous distributions have zero probability for each single event). In that case, you can simply report the predicted probability for 75km. (I don't think a discrete probability makes a lot of sense for distances walked, since distances are inherently continuous.)

Comment: Stephan, i do quantile forecasts but it gives me a wide range. For example i can only say there's 75% probability that i will walk less than 7km and more then 1km. But I can not say 75% probability, i will walk 5km tomorrow. So I'm trying to figure out if this is possible? Instead of getting a range, is it possible to give exact km and say 75% i will walk that much. Sorry for my English :(

Comment: It will not be possible with a continuous predictive distribution, but it will be with a discrete one. Look into count data models. (I don't think they are appropriate here, and I don't really see why you would be interested in a probability for an *exact* distance.)

Comment: I am trying to complete a study for my school i am working on. So we are trying to predict students daily walking distances. There's this idea comes from